# ListFragment OnListItemClick Not Calling When Using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, baseadapter, android-listfragment

I am using a custom `Adapter` like below and that works fine to actually display the data in my `ListFragment` normally:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(data.get(position));

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

My issue comes from when I want to utilise the `onListItemClick` method in my `ListFragment`, it simply never gets called:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

However I have found that if I just use a normal `ArrayAdapter` that I don't get any issues:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Although this is simply not feasible to use as I need the custom layout file to be implemented and therefore I wanted to use my custom `Adapter` like so:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), data);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

However as soon as I do, the clicking on the list row completely stops working. Please can someone give me some guidance as to why the `onListItemClick` method does not get called properly when I use my own custom `Adapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `getView()` method from the adapter, I see that you have a `CheckBox` in the list item. You need to add `android:focusable="false"` to it (as a matter of fact you need to do it to any control that is focusable by default).

Comment: Thank you! I thought this might be an issue (making part of the row inactive to clicks) but not for the whole list row. The `CheckBox` only takes up about a third of the row. Oh well, learn something new every day!

Comment: Your CheckBoxes are still "clickable", it's just that they don't get focus. I **think** that once you click the item, it tries to dispatch the focus to any of its children. If one is found, then, oh well. If not, dispatch touch outside, hence the callback happening in those cases. They key words are __I think__

Comment: Yeah sounds about right. I trust you. ;) Thank you very much for your help though. Saved me lots more inevitable pain.